# Apache Tomcat - Redirect requests from one folder to another?

Tags: tomcat

Let's say I have a folder in a web application, /my-tomcat-app/foo, and I wanted all requests to any file in this folder to be redirected to the page, /my-tomcat-app/index.html. What would I have to do to get this to happen?

I'm a newbie to Tomcat (as you can probably already tell from the nature of this question), so any help would be appreciated. I have already done some research on adding settings to web.xml, but I'm still unable to figure out exactly what to add to this file to get the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices but you can't do this with just web.xml configuration.

Possible solutions:

1. Write a servlet that just does `resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/index.html");` and map that Servlet to `/foo/*` and `/foo`
2. Use the [Tuckey Rewrite Filter](https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)
3. Use Tomcat's [Rewrite valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html)

There are probably others.